# retrieve a document using _id field that its one field contains highlighted words in elsaticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

I want to access a document in my index directly using its _id field and I want to highlight a word in `messageText`field, for this, I created below query but `highlight` attribute does not appear in result response.

```
{
    "query":{
        "term":{
            "_id": "1006382869737"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "tags_schema" : "styled",
        "fields" : {
            "messageText" : {
                "highlight_query":{
                    "term": {
                        "messageText":"car"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure that `car` is occurred in `messageText` field for document by Id `1006382869737`. so I'm sure `highlights` must exist in response, but it's not.

if it is important I'm using 2.3.4 version of elasticsearch. and query has been created according to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query). I'm not sure what `rescore_query` is in this documentation, if it is important please tell me how to edit my query, else give me another suggestion.

tnx :)

> Additional Information

I also try this below query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "must":[
                {
                    "term":{
                        "_id": "1006382869737"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "messageText":"car"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "messageText" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

but it causes no document hits.

Comment: How does the `messageText` field look like for the document with `_id: 1006382869737`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
My data comes from a server that I haven't access to its code. After many debugging I figure out that in some cases server send the text data in another field named `caption`.
Unfortunately The server has not a good documentation, that causes this problem.

Finally I find problem and add a more highlight_query for `caption` field and it's work fine now.